# No module named 'debug_toolbarnews'

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I did the following to install django-debug-toolbars

1. pip install django-debug-toolbar
2. added to middleware classes:

   MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware"
   ]
3. Added INTERNAL_IPS:

   INTERNAL_IPS = [
   "127.0.0.1",
   ]

4.Added debug_toolbar to installed apps

Code in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',include('news.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls'))
    ] + urlpatterns
```

i am getting "No module named 'debug_toolbarnews'" errors

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add the "debug_toolbar" in your INSTALLED_APPS?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   # ...
   "debug_toolbar",
   # ...
]
```

You can check the installation [guide](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-the-app).

Comment: "4.Added debug_toolbar to installed apps"